# how can one table name used more than once in query of postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I create view in the postgresql that for write query but error message display table name used more than once. How to solve this problem?

```
Query

    SELECT 
        tbcitizen.firstname || '-' || tbcitizen.middlename || '-' || tbcitizen.familyname as firstname,
        tbcitizen.dateofbirth,
        tbcity.cityname, 
        tbcontact.contactdetails, 
        tbcitizen.citizenidp

    FROM
        public.tbcitizen,
        public.tbaddress, 
        public.tbcity, 
        public.tbcontact

    INNER JOIN  
        tbcontact ON tbcitizen.citizenidp = tbcontact.referenceidf AND tbcontact.referencetypeidf = 1 AND 
tbcontact.isprimery = 1 INNER JOIN

            tbaddress ON tbcitizen.citizenidf = tbaddress.referenceidf AND tbaddress.referencetypeidf = 1 AND 
tbaddress.isprimery = 1 INNER JOIN

            tbcity ON tbaddress.cityidf = tbcity.cityidp
    WHERE 

      tbaddress.referencetypeidf = tbcitizen.citizenidp AND
      tbaddress.referenceidf = tbcitizen.citizenidp AND
      tbaddress.cityidf = tbcity.cityidp




 Error = table name "tbcontact" specified more than once
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As the error states that - your table **tbcontact** used 2 times as the source table. So it creates ambiguity for the postgres database engine. So to resolve this issue you have to use **table alias** with different name.

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side: it's as simple as `inner join tbcontact as contactinner`.